Disable PIN request for pairing on Rpi
when i try to connect the rpi bluetooth it showa a pin. i wat to be able to connect the rpi bluetooth without a pin. how can i disable the pin?


i try to disable the pin via bluetooth settings but it didn't work:


the term is PIN, not pin, because it is an acronym ... it is correct in the title

I wonder if this is even possible - given the RPi Org's fetishes re security. However: you might try this: Open a terminal window on yr RPi desktop, and run bluetoothctl. I'll leave it to you to read the docs, but (at least in my experience) bluetoothctl prompts you to accept/reject a PIN. If you accept it, you should be good for all eternity between those two MACs.
